# How do I paint over a material, then occlude the material where I painted?

Tags: materials, uv, texture-painting, texture-coordinates, shader-nodes

[image: picture]

I'm trying to texture paint a door and windows directly on a material surface, but the Diffuse shader makes it look more like it's painted on. To put it another way, I want to eliminate all material input in locations where I texture paint. How could I rearrange my shader nodes?

[image: shader]

Answer (score 1):

Your paint should be black&white ...

[image]

... and used as Factor for mixing shaders.

[image]

Or you can create new texture with Alpha zero and paint directly by color ...

[image]

... and use Alpha channel as Factor for mixing shaders.

[image]

Comment: How do I create a new texture with Alpha zero?

Comment: When you click New, properties window popups. Click on color and last parametr is A ... So just set it to zero.

Comment: That only works if I don't connect any inputs to the output's displacement, which I am trying to retain